Is it possible to create a closed source Flutter plugin?
I am building an SDK in Flutter and my client said that is should be closed source. For native IOS and Android I have created flutter module and compiled them to binary .framework and .aar files. I can use these binaries in a Native app but for Flutter it is not working because in every Flutter project contains its own Flutter and the flutter inside my SDK is overlooked and not being shown. So basically at this point I gave up on the idea of installing the Flutter module in binary format to a Flutter project. Is there any other way of creating a Flutter plugin which is closed source?

Ok, I decided to write the part of the code which needs to be hidden in native language and compiled it as binary package and included it in my flutter package.

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to compile Flutter code and then use those binaries in a different Flutter project, so you can't distribute a binary package. A compromise could be:

Move the important bits of your package into a C++ package.
Design an interface in Flutter/Dart for the C++ package as mentioned in the Flutter documentation.
Distribute the interface as a package with the binary blobs included.

The biggest pain point is that your C++ package must abide by the Dart FFI restrictions, which limit your binary-to-dart communication to only native types and also rule out web platforms. If the value of your package is mostly on the Flutter code (Widgets) then this method won't help.

Yeah, it is possible.
Flutter has a way to integrate with unpublished (private) packages.
Check out this link: https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages

still anyone who uses this private repository will be able to see the source code.

As already stated in a previous answer, yes you can create and distribute private packages. But as you said the code will be visible to everyone. What you can do is migrate the core functionalities into a backend system and provide these services via a plugin written in Dart(Flutter)
I developed a similar package and we used Django to do all the logical and processing part, while the Flutter plugin performed API queries, caching etc via an API key

There's already a thread where dart team has answered that there's no out of the box solution. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42863.
I think the closet solution is to obfuscate the source code.However, It can still be reverse engineered.
